# Excel Charts - Option to display errors as gaps doesn't work

Tags: excel, charts

In Excel 2013, I have a series of data that looks like this...

1, #N/A, 2, 3, 4

(N.B. The #N/A was generated using =NA() ).

I wish to make a line graph of this data, and have the #N/A show as a gap in the graph.

The standard advice for this is to use the 'Hidden and Empty Cells' options (right click on graph > Select Data... > Hidden and Empty Cells) to show empty cells as Gaps. However, this has no impact for me, the line graph is displayed in the same was as if the 'Connect data points with line' option was selected.

I've uploaded the example I'm referring to here to make this easy to see: http://www.filedropper.com/linegraphchartexample-gapsissue

I know that these gaps can be displayed, as I've seen it working on other line graphs in Excel (including graphs where #N/A was the value to be skipped over), I just haven't been able to replicate it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone reads this question, I found a solution which relies on using formulas to split the data into multiple data series, it's a pain to setup but it appears to be the least problematic way that Excel offers:

http://www.exceldashboardtemplates.com/how-to-show-gaps-in-a-line-chart-when-using-the-excel-na-function/

The simple summary is that you use formulas to create a new data series every time there is an #N/A value in the source data, then plot all the resulting data series, and format them so that they look the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to cheat by adding a second data series:

I have added a row to your data table which duplicates the data on row 2 if the cells to the left or the right contain #N/A.

```
B3=IF(OR(ISNA(A2),ISNA(B2),ISNA(C2)),B2,"")
```

The second data series is formatted with the same markers as the original line, but with a white line which obscures the blue one (as long as you've got your data series in the correct order).

[image]